# Changing default_ttl on Varnish 4 vcl file

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I am willing to change the default ttl value from the configuration file and not through the varnishd.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    ...
    set beresp.ttl = 24h;
    ...
}
```